# Angular order object in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an object like this:

```
var object = {
  'Shirts': {
    'Size': [
      {name: 'Large'},
      {name: 'Medium'}   
    ],
    'Color': [
      {name: 'Blue', image: 'imageURL'},
      {name: 'Red', image: 'imageURL'}
    ],
    '_attributes': [
      {position: 1}
    ]
  },
  'Pants': {
     'Size': [
       {name: 'Large'},
       {name: 'Medium'}
     ],
     '_attributes': [
       {position: 0}
     ]
   }
}
```

I'm trying to get an ng-repeat to sort an object structure like that based on position in ascending or descending order.

Also there is a chance that the `_attributes` key doesn't exist, in which case the position should be after anything else that does have position.

What should I put in the ng-repeat?

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, option) in object | orderBy:'WHATSHOULD BE HERE?'">
  {{key}}
</div>
```

The above would just print out:

```
Pants
Shirts
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit added a running version of the filter, honestly would see if the data could be better organized from the service layer or deal with this cleanup in a service rather than having it run all the time in a filter.

```js
angular
.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function(){
  this.object = {
  'Shirts': {
    'Size': [
      {name: 'Large'},
      {name: 'Medium'}   
    ],
    'Color': [
      {name: 'Blue', image: 'imageURL'},
      {name: 'Red', image: 'imageURL'}
    ],
    '_attributes': [
      {position: 1}
    ]
  },
  'Pants': {
     'Size': [
       {name: 'Large'},
       {name: 'Medium'}
     ],
     '_attributes': [
       {position: 0}
     ]
   }
}

})
.filter('myFilter', function(){
      return function(input){
        var newArray = [];
        var extra = [];
        if(!input) return newArray;
        for(prop in input)
        {
          input[prop].displayName = prop;
          if(input.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            if(input[prop]._attributes){
              newArray[input[prop]._attributes[0].position] = input[prop];
            }
            else{
              extra.push(input[prop])
            }
          }
        }
        return newArray.concat(extra)
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="datum in myCtrl.object | myFilter">
    {{datum.displayName|json}}
  </div>

</div>
```

OrderBy filter is meant to work on arrays or other "collections"  (see the arguments section) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy an object in JS is an unordered collection so doesn't have an inherent order despite browsers being pretty consistent about it, it isn't well defined by specifications what order should be used.  That said you can make a custom filter pretty easily and just do whatever you want to do logically in the filter with whatever type of object gets passed into your filter.  To define a custom filter it is just a new function that takes some input which in this case would be the object and you return a new item in this case would probably return an array for the ng-repeat to repeat over and the array has a fixed ordering based on how you push objects in or otherwise populate the array.

Generically a filter definition looks like:

```
.filter('myFilter', function(/*injectables here like $http*/){
  return function(input/*, other args here if needed  input is object in your case*/) {
    //Do stuff in here to order the object how you want or put it in an array
    var retObj = {newStuff:'hello', oldStuff: input};
    return retObj;

  }
})
```

Usage like

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, option) in object | myFilter">
  {{key}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> in your sample if you want use `orderBy`, `filter` as well, you have
>   to change your object as array and this (`array`) much better work
>   than `object`.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);


app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
  var object = {
    'Shirts': {
      'Size': [{
          name: 'Large'
        },
        {
          name: 'Medium'
        }
      ],
      'Color': [{
          name: 'Blue',
          image: 'imageURL'
        },
        {
          name: 'Red',
          image: 'imageURL'
        }
      ],
      '_attributes': [{
        position: 1
      }]
    },
    'Pants': {
      'Size': [{
          name: 'Large'
        },
        {
          name: 'Medium'
        }
      ],
      '_attributes': [{
        position: 0
      }]
    }
  }


  var convertToArray = function(singleObject) {
    var items = [];

    for (var key in singleObject) {
      var newObject = {
        name: key,
        options: object[key]
      }
      items.push(newObject);
    }

    return items;
  }

  $scope.items = convertToArray(object);

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <button ng-click="reverse = !reverse">reverse items by name</button>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'name':reverse">
      <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
      <ul>
        <li ng-if="item.options.Color"><b>Colors</b></li>
        <li ng-repeat="color in item.options.Color">
          {{color.name}}
        </li>
        <li><b>Sizes</b></li>
        <li ng-repeat="size in item.options.Size">
          {{size.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```